# How can I get crontab to successfully start WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to run an hourly cron job that pulls some code, starts rails and executes some tests (the code pulling and tests don't really matter for this, as they work fine).
Here's the crontab line from my user (i'm on Ubuntu 10.04):

```
0 */1 * * * /home/me/src/dev-setup/scripts/hourly_ui_test_cron_script
```

and here's the script itself (minus the comments i echo to myself, the git and test stuff):

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=me
HOME=/home/$USER/
DISPLAY=:0
source $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
PATH=/home/$USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/$USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/$USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/$USER/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
cd $HOME/src/project
pgrep -f ruby | xargs kill -9
rails s -e test >> hourly_test.log
```

and this mostly works, except that my WEBrick starts and immediately exits with no error; here's the log:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in test on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
```

and there's nothing registered in the rails log. I've tried running just rails s, i've tried running the script from root's crontab; nothing works (the script runs if i just execute it from command line). 
Has anyone seen this?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding -d to script which will daemonise. See what happens with that or do you need running in foreground?

Seems a very strange thing to do though generally so I hope you've got good reason to be using webbrick in this way.